# Moving data between dissimilar tables in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a set of tables that track various properties of equipment parts based on the type of part.  Some part types share certain properties, for example length, weight, last order date, etc.  However there are also some properties that are unique to a specific part type.  For example, parts that are of type "motor" would have a voltage but would not have a lumens rating, as would a part of type "led"... although an "led" part would also have a voltage.

Occasionally, a part's type will be changed and when that happens, our database requires that new records be created in the appropriate tables for tracking the part's new properties.  We want to be able to also copy over the previous shared property values from the previous parts type fields that are common between the old and new parts type tables.  In cases where the old and new fields are equivilent, they will share the exact same field name, i.e., the 'weight' field will be named 'weight' in both tables.

In VBA, it is straightforward to loop through the fields in both tables and compare field names for a match.  When a match is found, the data then needs to get copied from the old parts type table to the corresponding field in the new table.  The tricky part (which I'm hoping for advice on) is how to efficiently UPDATE the new field when the data type can be anything, e.g., text, number, date, OLE object, etc.  Of course, the syntax for bounding each of these is different -- text fields require a single quote, dates require a pound sign, numbers don't need anything, not sure what an OLD object needs.

My current thinking is to set a bounding character based on the data type of the field and then add those characters while building the SQL string that would then be executed to update the new table.  Here is some pseudo code and the SQL statement I was thinking I'd use.  The tdf objects are DAO tabledefs, the fld objects are DAO field objects.

Questions:

1. is there a better approach (more efficient, cleaner, reliable, standard)
2. should I setup a recordset to actually access the data in the old
       table or is DLookup() a decent choice given that there will only be
       about 50 - 100 fields moved at a time?
3. I've never moved OLE object between tables. No doubt, other
       StackOverflow posts will address this.  But if you have thoughts
       then I'd be happy to hear them.

   ```
   <nested loop to match old and new field names>

       <if a matching field is found, then>

           strSQL = "UPDATE " & tdfTo.Name & " SET " & fldTo.Name & " = " & DLookup(fldFrom.Name, tdfFrom.Name, "part_number = " & strPartNum) & " WHERE part_number = '" & strPartNum & "';"
           CurrentDB.Execute strSQL

   <end nested matching loop>r
   ```

Comment: Check out Gustav's `CSql` function, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36421361/3820271 - it handles a lot of data types (not OLE though).

Comment: Thanks, @andre, that's a clean function and I may use it.